# error MongoNotConnectedError when running yield file from unit test nodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I have a file that containt yield and co logic in node JS, the code look like below

```
module.export = {
  moduleName(payload, callback){
    //first logic
    // second logic
    co(function*(){
      yield user.findById(somerandomid)
      //error when find user by id
    })
  }
}
```

and this is my unit test code

```
 beforeAll(async () => {
  await dbHandler.connect();
  //this part to connecto to mongodb
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await dbHandler.disconnect();
});

afterEach(async () => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

it("test",()=>{
   moduleName(somepayload)
})
```

so when i run my test case i got error :

```
MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations
```

i know this error because not connected to mongodb but i already create connection in beforeAll function, i have tried to wrap my connection in test case to yield like below

```
it('ts',async()=>{
  co(function*(){
    yield dbHandler.connect()
    yield moduleName(somepayload)
  }
})
```

but it did not work, any ideas?